# VB6: How do I properly store class objects in a collection?

Tags: vba, vb6

I'm looking at a legacy VB6 app, and trying to understand how VB6 Collections work. Using the *Collection.Add* method, I am finding that the collection just exists of its last added option, repeated. *e.g. if I add 1,2,3,4,and 5 to a collection, I will get 5, 5, 5, 5, and 5 back as the collection contents.*

In my test case, I have an encapsulation class module, **EncapsulationClass.cls** that stores some simple strings. Its implementation:

```
Option Explicit

'ivars
Private pEntityId As String
Private pEntityName As String

'properties
    'pEntityId
    Public Property Get entityId() As String
        Let entityId = pEntityId
    End Property

    Private Property Let entityId(ByVal inEntityId As String)
        Let pEntityId = inEntityId
    End Property


    'pEntityName
    Public Property Get entityName() As String
        Let entityName = pEntityName
    End Property

    Private Property Let entityName(ByVal inEntityName As String)
        Let pEntityName = inEntityName
    End Property


'constructor
    Public Sub init(ByVal inEntityId As String, ByVal inEntityName As String)
        Let entityId = inEntityId
        Let entityName = inEntityName
    End Sub
```

I want to store several instances of these in an iterable object, so I used a *Collection*.

In my test case, I have this simple function:

```
Private Function getACollection() As Collection
    Dim col As New Collection
    Dim data(0 To 5) As String
    data(0) = "zero"
    data(1) = "one"
    data(2) = "two"
    data(3) = "three"
    data(4) = "four"
    data(5) = "five"

    For Each datum In data
        Dim encap As New EncapClass
        encap.init datum, datum & "Name"
        col.Add encap
    Next

    'return
    Set getACollection = col
End Function
```

This function is then used in the following simple logic:

```
Private Sub Form_Load()
    Dim col As Collection
    Set col = getACollection()

    For Each i In col
        Debug.Print i.entityId, i.entityName
    Next i
End Sub
```

I would expect the output to be:

```
one oneName
two twoName
three threeName
four fourName
five fiveName
```

However, instead, I simply get a repetition of the last element added, five times.

```
five fiveName
five fiveName
five fiveName
five fiveName
five fiveName
```

Is there something I'm missing, syntactically? Looking through various [books](http://books.google.com/books?id=kVqB5hjNsScC&pg=PA361&lpg=PA361&dq=object%20in%20collection%20%22visual%20basic%206%22&source=bl&ots=18_vsvRT-J&sig=lim7SXDoYkO-J-LS_niX9qIse5c&hl=en&sa=X&ei=n5zeUqu-H-Of2QWo04HoBw&ved=0CD0Q6AEwAg#v=onepage&q=object%20in%20collection%20%22visual%20basic%206%22&f=false), collections are appended with the Add method, and work as expected.

Comment: `getACollection` lacks a return statement for one thing,

Comment: Edit: You are correct I did not paste that properly!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The lack of a `set` is effectively reusing the same single instance of `encap` so changes within the loop modify the single repeated reference already in the collection.

To fix:

```
 Dim encap As EncapClass

 For Each datum In data
     set encap = New EncapClass
     encap.init datum, datum & "Name"
     col.Add encap
 Next
```